# PHP pull SQL as text only

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a login system that gives users the ability to have profiles. 
But I noticed if I update my Bio with `</div> </div> </div>` it is read and will break the page. Using PHP inside the bio also is working. I know there is a way to make it pull as text only, and not as active php, but I am forgetting the Class/Div settings to do so.

I know I am probably missing something obvious, I assume its something along the line of

```
<li><strong> Bio: </strong>&nbsp;**<plaintext>**<?php echo $row['bio']; ?>**</plaintext>**</li>
```

Comment: You need to sanitise your data so that HTML tags are blocked, or are stripped out, or are made harmless by encoding them. Bit odd that including PHP inside the bio also works...can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In displaying database results, its recommended to convert all html tags to their special entities.

In php, you can use either

**1.) htmlspecialchars()**

**2.) htmlentities()**

For instance

```
$string ="<b>hello</b>";

echo htmlentities(string);
```

If you are running xampp server, you will need to implement htmlentities twice, I do not know whether if that is a bug with php

something like

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities(string));
```

In a nutshell, you can use
`strip_tags()` to strip out all html out of a variable during data insertion and updates as it comes from form inputs and use `htmlspecialchars or htmlentities` when dispalying database results to user

so in your own case this will do

```
<?php echo htmlentities(htmlentities($row['bio'])); ?>
```

or

```
  <?php echo htmlentities($row['bio']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this function it will take out all the html tags:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row['bio']); ?>
```

Would that be helpful to your issue?

A reference for the [strip_tags function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp).

Comment: Let me try it, it looks like it might do the trick. Just dont want people to put PHP script in their bio to break the site.

Comment: @JakeJigsaw it shouldn't be possible for PHP inside the bio field to be executed. Can you give an example of where that's been happening for you? They might be able to execute Javascript though (at least until you apply the change to strip the tags, anyway).

Comment: this worked worked for me, but I ended up going with the method posted below. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In a righteous order of operations, you will filter/sanitize/validate user input *before you take any action* (e.g. display, save as file, insert into database) with it. If you only sanitize for output (removing HTML, Javascript etc.), it's possible that in time the embedded PHP will end up somewhere it can be executed (e.g. a cache file with a .php extension, or wherever else).

You will want to filter out at least:

- Any HTML code
- Any Javascript code
- Any PHP code

And really, anything that shouldn't exist to begin with, really shouldn't float around anywhere persistent.

One thing to consider is, no matter how grand your filtering/sanitization models are, chances are something will eventually slip through, since the permutations are so extensive. Therefore, rather **filter out anything that doesn't belong**, instead of **targeting particular things**. *Do not* rely on `strip_tags()` as your only measure to prevent [XSS injections](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) etc., it's easy to evade. You might find some relief with `htmlspecialchars()`, but it's definitely not the gold standard.

Suppose, for example, you really only want your users to fill in plain text, spaces, and common punctuation. Then you might for example do `$input = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9 ,.!?_-]#', '', $input);`, which would remove anything that isn't `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, space or `,.!?_-` punctuation characters. (The regex above is simply an example so you get the general idea, you will probably not want to use it as-is.) Bottom line: **White-list, don't black-list**.

If your want to allow your users to format their input, then consider using a light markup language like [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or [AsciiDoc](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/what-is-asciidoc/) for bold, italics, lists etc. (like you see happening here at StackOverflow), that you then parse into HTML when rendering the page.